# when form is submit then a error is occur

Tags: django, forms

[image]

when I click on remmber and submit the form then a error is occured

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /seller/

'out'

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/seller/
Django Version:     2.2.7
Exception Type:     MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    

'out'

Exception Location:     /home/krishan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/datastructures.py in __getitem__, line 80
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python3
Python Version:     3.6.8
Python Path:    

['/home/krishan/Desktop/property',
 '/usr/lib/python36.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6',
 '/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
 '/home/krishan/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages']

Server time:    Tue, 26 Nov 2019 10:27:23 +0000
```

views.py:

```
def register_seller(request):
    rm = request.POST.get('remember','off')
    if rm == 'on':
        if request.method == 'POST':
            userName = request.POST['userName']
            state = request.POST['state']
            city = request.POST['city']
            full_address = request.POST['fulladdress']
            out = request.FILES['out']
            bedroom_no  = request.POST['bedroom_no']
            kithen_img = request.FILES['kitchen']
            swimming_img  = request.FILES['swimming']
            phone = request.POST['phone']
            email = request.POST['email']
            price = request.POST['price']
            floor = request.POST['floor']
            squre = request.POST['squre']
            garden_img = request.FILES['garden']
            each = seller_detail(state=state,city=city,full_address=full_address,pro_img=out,username=userName,bedroom_no=bedroom_no,kitchen_img=kithen_img,swimming_img=swimming_img,phone=phone,email=email,price=price,floor=floor,squre=squre,gerden_img=garden_img)
            each.save()
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return render(request,'all/seller_input.html',{'remember':'Please checkout the button'})
    else:
        return render(request,'all/seller_input.html')
```

Comment: You'll need to show how you're rendering the form in the template.

Comment: Are you using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form? as you are trying to send files, you should have `<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">`

Comment: This is exactly why you should be using Django's form framework rather than accessing POST data directly.

Comment: What solarismoke and Pedram Parsian just said - but by all means do yourself, your application users and anyone that will ever have to work on this code (maintainers, admins etc) a favor : [**USE DJANGO FORMS !!!**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/2.2/topics/forms/) - proper form validation is not trivial, and not doing it right leads to huge security issues.

Comment: i am not understanding what you saying

Comment: i am using <form action="{% url 'seller' %}" id="log" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: The error says that `request.FILES` does not have a key `"out"`, i.e. there isn't a file uploaded with this key. You should not access keys directly like this in a python dictionary if you're not sure they exist. As brunodesthuilliers says, you should use a `Form` in your view to process the data, instead of trying to process it like this yourself. Read the link (from top to bottom!) he added in his comment.

Comment: my problem is that when user click on remember me button and submit the form without filling other details like username,city,state